# Club two labels into one as Grafana variable

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I want to generate a grafana variable containing unique value `application_name-result` based on these data:

```
{app="abc-api", application_name="abc-processor", application_type="processor", stream_name="test-stream", result="success"}
{app="abc-api", application_name="abc-processor", application_type="processor", stream_name="test-stream", result="failure"}
{app="abc-api", application_name="abc-processor", application_type="processor", stream_name="test-stream", result="duplicate"}

{app="xyz-api", application_name="xyz-processor", application_type="processor", stream_name="test-stream", result="duplicate"}
{app="xyz-api", application_name="xyz-processor", application_type="processor", stream_name="test-stream", result="success"}
{app="xyz-api", application_name="xyz-processor", application_type="processor", stream_name="test-stream", result="failure"}
```

I can create those separately but unable to club it together, for example:

```
stream_name :: label_values(stream_name)    
application_name :: label_values({stream_name="$stream_name"},application_name)
results :: label_values(document_index_total{stream_name="$stream_name",application_name=~"$application_name"},result)
```

Kindly guide me the steps.

I want the variable output as:

```
abc-processor-success
abc-processor-failure
abc-processor-duplicate

xyz-processor-success
xyz-processor-failure
xyz-processor-duplicate
```